# What does the canvas.drawColor mean in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

If I want to give a background color to my canvas , I use the below code :

```
 Paint redPaint = new Paint()
  ..color = Colors.red
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
canvas.drawPaint(redPaint);
```

And I found the other method is canvas.drawColor(Color , BlendMode), but it looks like not what I expected .

```
canvas.drawColor(Colors.red, BlendMode.color)
```

or

```
canvas.drawColor(Colors.red, BlendMode.clear)
```

Does it mean that I can not use canvas.drawColor() to give canvas a background color ?

Comment: Try this "canvas.drawColor(Colors.red, BlendMode.src)"

Comment: @Won, thank you and it works . But I still have a puzzle about this . It seems that I don't have a clear concept about BlendMode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only your source color, ie no blending than use `BlendMode.src`.

You can learn about all the available blend modes here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html